# KeyEvent target for Windows Firefox remains on hidden button

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-closure

I have a div with several buttons in a form. When one of the buttons is clicked, this div is hidden and a new div is displayed. In my case, I am also having the button click trigger an ajax call for some data to populate the newly displayed div. The div that loads is a game that captures key events to allow the player to play.

In Firefox on Windows, I notice that all key events are being targeted at the button that was clicked on the first div, rather than at the body element. This means that the `enter` key re-clicks that button (restarting the game). If I disable the buttons when I switch divs, key events do not get triggered at all (making it unplayable).

What would a good strategy be to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an answer to my own question or a workaround, but it looks like I can call:

```
document.activeElement.blur()
```

I've added this to my button's onclick function and this seems to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't get the events without blurring since key events should bubble up. However setting the focus to some element that does not react to key events in unexpected ways seems like a good solution to your problem.